# Passing object instance to constructor using Kodein

Tags: kotlin, kodein

I'm new to Kotlin and Kodein. I'm trying to use a Java library and I need to pass a singleton to one of my constructors. I can't figure out how to get an actual instance. Since I need to pass an instance to the constructor I believe I need to be using DKodein so lazy loading isn't being used?

```
val kodein: DKodein = Kodein.direct {
    bind<DataSource>() with singleton {
        val config = HikariConfig()
        config.jdbcUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb"
        config.username = "username"
        config.password = "password"
        config.driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
        HikariDataSource(config)
    }
    bind<DatabaseContext>() with singleton {
        // I thought kodein.instance() here would provide the DataSource
        // instance I declared above. However I get the error (from Intellij)
        // TypeInference failed. Expected type mismatch.
        // Required: DataSource!
        // Found: KodeinProperty<???>
        DatabaseContext(kodein.instance()) 
    }
}
```

Is there any easy way to achieve this? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks.

Comment: `kodein` cannot be accessed within its own initialization expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the initialization block of Kodein you must use `instance()` without `kodein.`.

```
//use Kodein instead of DKodein
val kodein: Kodein = Kodein {
    bind<DataSource>() with singleton {
        val config = HikariConfig()
        config.jdbcUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb"
        config.username = "username"
        config.password = "password"
        config.driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
        HikariDataSource(config)
    }
    bind<DatabaseContext>() with singleton {
        //use instance() without kodein
        //or use dkodein.instance()
        DatabaseContext(instance()) 
    }
}
```

Kodein distinguishes between `DKodein` and `Kodein`.

- `DKodein` allows the direct access of instances.
- `Kodein` creates delegated properties via `by`.

The initialization block of Kodein provides access to both interfaces. But `dkodein` is the default. If you use `kodein.instance()` the property initializer version is used.

Outside of the initialization block, you can access `DKodein` like this:

```
val datasource: DataSource = kodein.direct.instance()
```